# jQuery ajax request causes 'not well-formed' error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, non-well-formed

When trying to dynamically load a Javascript file using jQuery I keep getting a "not well-formed" error message. I have found people with similar problems on here but have yet to see a resolution provided.

My main script uses:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.js',
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true,
    success: loadScriptReturn
});

function loadScriptReturn() { }
```

My dynamically loaded script (test.js) in its simplest form:

```
alert('Hello World.');
```

Since I am specifically loading this as a script MIME type it eliminates the possibility that Firefox is confused as to what type of file is being pulled in. Is there a way to solve this problem? Alternatively, is there a way to shut off this specific error in Firefox? (note: this is an error, not a warning, which is extremely annoying because I do want to see subsequent error messages -- bad on Firefox as this *should* have been a warning, not an error)

Keep in mind, this example WORKS, but it still produces an error. Given how many scripts I need to load dynamically it will be tedious trying to sort through "real" error messages if I can't find a way to get rid of this.

Thank you in advance to contributors!

Comment: I doubt this is Firefox giving you this message.  More likely Firebug.

Comment: Yes, probably Firebug - in addition, you should not be using `ajax()`  to fetch JS script - you should be using `getScript()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ - While one is shorthand for the other, it is more clear.

Comment: Also check your encoding. If you are using UTF-8, make sure that you arn't using a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) because this can cause all sorts of headaches.

Comment: You're right, Firebug error, but I did find a solution (see comment below)... thanks everyone for checking into this. I spent 3-4 hours yesterday and 1-2 hours today trying to figure this out. Turns out this is only thrown when using Ajax locally; remotely: no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found several questions that may help you:

- [not well-formed error in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405702/not-well-formed-error-in-firefox)
- ["not well-formed" error in Firefox when loading JSON file with XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677902/not-well-formed-error-in-firefox-when-loading-json-file-with-xmlhttprequest)

The general consensus is that you need to change the MIME type to `application/json`.

Comment: This error message is only thrown locally when dynamically loading a script. The minute you start working off a remote server the error message does not appear. As far as I can tell Firefox doesn't see the MIME when loading a local file (bug?).

If you're someone out there who is receiving this same error message, try uploading all your files to a remote server to see if it goes away... I spent 3-4 hours trying to diagnose the problem... hopefully this saves someone else some time.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to load script dynamically:

```
$('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>');
```

Comment: I tried your code (thanks for that by the way) but I still recieved the same error message. Interestingly though, I found a solution while attempting your code.

Comment: This error message is only thrown locally when dynamically loading a script. The minute you start working off a remote server the error message does not appear. As far as I can tell Firefox doesn't see the MIME when loading a local file (bug?).

If you're someone out there who is receiving this same error message, try uploading all your files to a remote server to see if it goes away... I spent 3-4 hours trying to diagnose the problem... hopefully this saves someone else some time.

Comment: just te be sure, try to wrap your js file by
//<![CDATA[
  -- your JS code --
//]]>
I think this may fix the error!