# Reload url in javascript with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to refresh an affiliate URL which is inside a piece of JavaScript with AJAX, but I can't get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var mdWidgetUrl = "https://herecomestheurl";
        var s = document.createElement("script"), 
            s1 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.async = true;
        s.src = mdWidgetUrl;
        s1.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s1);
    })();
    function fetchdata(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 's.src',
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data){
                // Perform operation on return value
                alert(data);
            },
            complete:function(data){
                setTimeout(fetchdata,10000);
            }
        });
    }        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(fetchdata,10000);
    });                
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is to AJAX reload the URL, which is known as "mdWidgetUrl", every 10 seconds without refreshing the whole page. This code doesn't work, because I don't know how to tag the `s.src` within the AJAX function.

Comment: If you're going to edit and just remove all the content from the question then you might just delete it. This is not a valid edit

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to delete it, but it seems that you can't delete a post when someone already posted a reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look to the different [settings](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) of your AJAX call:

### `url:`

When you try:

```
url: 's.src',
```

you are not passing the content of the `src` property of the `s` object; you are literally passing the string `"s.src"`. But even if you do:

```
url: s.src,
```

it won't work because `s` is out of scope. `s` was declared inside an IIFE ( `(function() {...` ) and it lives just inside it. You can not access it from outside.

Instead, after you create your `s` script, you can give it an `id`. Like this:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.id = "mdWidgetScript";
```

Then, you can easily retrieve the value of the `src` attribute from the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: $("#mdWidgetScript").attr('src'),
```

Note that using an `id` is not mandatory. You could find the script like you found `s1`, selecting the first element with a `<script>` tag:

```
url: document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].getAttribute("src");
// or with jQuery
url: $("script:eq(0)").attr('src');
```

I just find using an `id` a cleaner and more bulletproof way.

### `type:`

It is an alias for `method`. You are retrieving data from the server, not sending to. Switch `POST` to `GET` (or leave this setting out, since `GET` is the default). Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/715335/5247200) about the differences.

### `dataType`:

You should set the `dataType` accordingly (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18701282/5247200)). If the URL points to a script, use `dataType: "script",`. Actually, you could use [`$.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) which is a shorthand method for this kind of AJAX call.

---

If after properly tuning your settings you still have troubles:

- Check for errors in the console.
- Ensure the data being send is well-formed
- Read this other questions:

  - [Why does jQuery insist my plain text is not “well-formed”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1828228/5247200)
  - [jQuery.ajax success callback function not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2787180/5247200)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly enough I don't have access to the script where the s.src is coming from. Also I don't have much understanding of JS in general. So I think your answer is pretty clear, I can't implement it. Thanks for the effort anyways!

Comment: @ZnortDesigns - There is just one script in your code so I guess you mean  that you don't have access to the code inside the IIFE. As you can read at the end of the answer, you can get the `src` attribute **without** using an id. In that case no edition of the `s.src` is required.

Comment: @ZnortDesigns - In case the last bit was confusing: just replace `url: 's.src',` for `url: $("script:eq(0)").attr('src'),`. Maybe you need to change the `0` if other scripts are being loaded before in the same page.

Comment: I tried to implement it the way you told, it's now showing the product again, but it doesn't refresh after 10 seconds. Can I send you the URL, so that you can see how the code is looking now?

Comment: @ZnortDesigns. sure, send the URL. Using `setInterval` is not the way to fix it. If the `complete` callback is not running is because you have a deeper problem with your AJAX call. Read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2787180/5247200). Also, I have updated my answer, so far I focus just on the `url:` bit.

Comment: @ZnortDesigns I would recommend adding, underneath the line where you set `s.async`: `s.id = "affiliateLinkSource";` Then, in the `$.ajax` section change `'s.src'` to `$("#affiliateLinkSource").attr('src')`

Comment: @SamJakob - That's exactly what my answer is about.

Comment: @David I know, that's why I left a comment instead of a separate answer. I just figured using an ID was a cleaner / more reliable approach and I tried to clarify what you meant.