# jQuery get plaintext file: "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to use jQuery to load the contents of a plaintext (.bib) file. Despite my best attempts, the file seems to be interpreted as XML, leading to a parsing error.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "publications.bib",
        contentType: "text/plain",
        dataType: "text",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }, 'text');
});
```

As you can see, I'm desperately trying to make it interpret it as text and not XML. How do I fix this?

The full error is:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost/publications.bib
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

Comment: What is the `Content-type:` header that the server is sending?

Comment: Apologies, how would I check this? I added             success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type"));
            }, which returned null

Comment: Use the Network tab in Developer Tools to see the response headers.

Comment: Content-Type text/plain, but Type xml (from network tab)

Comment: Note that the `contentType:` option to `$.ajax()` makes no difference in a `GET` request, since it doesn't send any contents.

Comment: You're sure you saw `text/plain` in the **Response** headers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery insist my plain text is not "well-formed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828228/why-does-jquery-insist-my-plain-text-is-not-well-formed)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a minimal test case based on your code. Apparently it's the file extension which makes jquery think it's an XML.

Replaced .bib with a .txt and it works as you want.

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "pub.txt",
    contentType: "text/plain",
    dataType: "text",
    type: "GET",
    success: function ( response ){
        console.log( response );
    }
}, 'text' );
```